# sitecore, too long item url, multiple sites

Tags: sitecore

I host two sites in a single sitecore environment.
I've modified web.config so that

```xml
<site hostName="subdomain1.domain.com" startItem="/home" ... />
<site hostName="subdomain2.domain.com" startItem="/SecondSite/Homepage" ... />
```

The problem is that menu links I generate in xslt rendering using sc:path(.) are too long.

```
http://subdomain2.domain.nl/sitecore/content/SecondSite/CaptivatingPage.aspx
```

I want the links look like

```
http://subdomain2.domain.nl/CaptivatingPage.aspx
```

Please, give me a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The true root of the site is SiteRoot + StartItem, thus in your case it is `/sitecore/content/SecondSIte/Homepage`. The page you generate a link to in your XSL rendering is not under the root of the site - it is the same level as the Homepage.

`sc:path(.)` should give you a friendly link, and for each page under the Homepage it will be `http://subdomain2.domain.nl/EachPage.aspx`, but for the items outside the root it will concatenate it with the full path: `/sitecore/content/blabla...`

So, try to move CaptivatingPage under the Homepage, and you'll get what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the CMS version you are using, but in the web.config, see if there is a linkManager element. If so, try defining the shortenUrls=true attribute.

Another option is to create an xslt extension function that overrides the path method, specifying your own UrlOptions logic.